# Move sidebar from left to right side

Tags: css

I'm trying to move the menu sidebar from the left to right side. The changes to .main-sidebar and .main (the content) swapping the float values left/right breaks the menu.

Here's a demo page https://demo.competethemes.com/?theme=author

```
@media all and (min-width: 59.375em) {
  .main-sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 27.775%;
    padding: 3em 1.85185%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }

@media all and (min-width: 59.375em) {
  .main {
    float: left;
    padding: 3em 5.555%;
    width: 72.215%;
  }
```

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the easiest way is to use transform to mirror the layout .

You can load this part of CSS after any other css rules/files :

```
@media all and (min-width: 59.375em) {
  body, 
  #main-sidebar, 
  #main ,
  footer.site-footer[role="contentinfo"] {
       transform:scale(-1,1)
  }
}
```

if you want to see what it does , add a delayed transition :

```
@media all and (min-width: 59.375em) {
  body, 
  #main-sidebar, 
  #main ,
  footer.site-footer[role="contentinfo"] {
       transform:scale(-1,1);
       transition:1s 1s
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following command to the global css field.
don't Copy in the `@media`

```
.main-sidebar{
 float:right;
}
```

I hope your problem is solved

Comment: Nope it partially works, on scrolling it moves to left side again. Javascript is causing styles to reset again on scroll, you can improve the answer by adding the js code